# Rename keys in object replace it to numbers make correct sorting

Tags: javascript

I have object, i need:

1. Remove all properties and leave only keys `numeric`
2. Rename all keys from `numeric` to real numbers
3. Save sort by current structure

```js
// Input object look like here
{
  "name": "Query1",
  "numeric": [
    {
      "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-2",
      "numeric": [],
    },
    {
      "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-3",
      "numeric": [
        {
          "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-4",
          "numeric": [
            {
              "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-6",
              "numeric": [],
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-5",
          "numeric": [],
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
}

// Output should be like this
{
  1: {
    2: '',
    3: {
      4: {
        6: '',
      },
      5: '',
    },
  },
};

// Numbers come frome here
{
  "1": {
    "trad": "Query1"
  },
  "2": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-2"
  },
  "3": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-3"
  },
  "4": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-4"
  },
  "5": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-6"
  },
  "6": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-5"
  }
}
```

I used for and lodash but any result

Comment: Do you have some code that you've tried that isn't working? Please note that it is expected to show what you've tried (even if it isn't working), so that we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Where the numbers come from? Random?

Comment: @kennarddh they appear to be sequential, but if this was implemented recursively (which would be the only sensible solution) then it would be `4 : { 5 : '' }, 6 : ''` - getting it to be as OP requested would make this much more difficult.

Comment: You *might* like to include the other table if your numbers are *lookups* not just sequential.  Seems like it might be relevant...

Comment: @WillKrimmer Please edit your question to include the other object.

Comment: Show us what your tried and we can help debug - but this isn't a place to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object key cannot be number

You can use recursive to solve this

```js
const input = {
  "name": "Query1",
  "numeric": [{
      "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-2",
      "numeric": [],
    },
    {
      "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-3",
      "numeric": [{
          "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-4",
          "numeric": [{
            "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-6",
            "numeric": [],
          }],
        },
        {
          "name": "Basic Query Tasknode-5",
          "numeric": [],
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
}

const lookupRaw = {
  "1": {
    "trad": "Query1"
  },
  "2": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-2"
  },
  "3": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-3"
  },
  "4": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-4"
  },
  "5": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-6"
  },
  "6": {
    "trad": "Basic Query Tasknode-5"
  }
}

const lookup = Object.entries(lookupRaw).reduce((acc, [key, {
  trad
}]) => {
  acc[trad] = key

  return acc
}, {})

const recursive = (data) => {
  const lookupNumber = lookup[data.name]

  if (data.numeric.length === 0) {
    return ''
  }

  const result = {}

  for (const row of data.numeric) {
    result[lookup[row.name]] = recursive(row)
  }

  return result
}

const result = recursive(input)

console.log(result)
```